# ajax: no data from local server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using php on a linux machine. My html code issues an ajax request to the local apache server (http://localhost), and the data from the server should be printed out on the screen. However, nothing gets printed.

The code on the "client" side (the html file which I load in the browser) is:

```
<html> 
    <body>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function ajaxFunction(){
                var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

                try{
                    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (e){
                    // Internet Explorer Browsers
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e){
                            // Something went wrong
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if( ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 ){
                        document.writeln( ajaxRequest.responseText );
                    }
                }
                ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/s.php", true);
                ajaxRequest.send(null); 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the "server" script (which is /var/www/s.php) is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo date("H:i:s"); 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your code

1. Check Apache access log that s.php was loaded
2. If it loaded then add debug alert function to onreadystatechange callback function
3. If this function is called then check what return code it received: `alert(ajaxRequest.readyState);`
4. If code is 4 then check what content it returned: `alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);`

Comment: Thanks. following your suggestions, I confirmed the server side script (s.php) is executed. However, ajaxRequest.responseText is empty. When I run s.php alone (http://localhost/s.php) it does display the date (as expected) on the browser page. any suggestions the date isnt returned in ajaxRequest.responseText?. TIA

Comment: solved. the request was empty due to the cross domain issue. when I called the script with ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/s.php", true); it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything calling `ajaxFunction` when the page loads, so the request is never sent.